# Ajax form not receiving response from PHP form handler

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, mailchimp

I have an Ajax / PHP form that worked just fine when I was building a custom AMP site. The form response messages were handled with the AMP Mustache component.

I've replaced the AMP components as I'm no longer using AMP and now I'm having trouble getting a response back from my form handler.

**Here's my HTML form:**

I'm omitting a few fields for brevity. Spam fields for MailChimp for example.

```html
<form 
    action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mailchimp-post.php"
    method="post"
    id="subscriber_form"
    name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"
    class="validate"
    target="_top">

    <input 
        type="text" 
        value="" 
        name="name" 
        id="name"
        placeholder="first name" required>

    <input
        type="email"
        value=""
        name="email"
        id="email"
        placeholder="email address"
        required>

    <input 
        type="submit" 
        value="<?php the_field('button_label'); ?>" 
        name="subscribe" 
        id="mc-embedded-subscribe" 
        class="button">
</form>
```

**Here's my form submission JavaScript:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $form = $('#subscriber_form')

  if ($form.length > 0) {
    $('form input[type="submit"]').on('click', function (event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault()
      register($form)
    })
  }


  function register($form) {
    // Set the submit button text to "sending..."
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('sending...');

    $.ajax({
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize(),
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function (err) { alert('Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later.') },
      success: function (data) {
        // Reset the submit button to "subscribe"
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('subscribe');

        if (data.status === 'success') { 
          // Do things upon success
          alert('success');
        } else { 
          // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user.
          alert('error');
        }
      }
    })
  };
});
```

***And here's my PHP form handler:**

This form handler is using a PHP wrapper to send subscriber data to MailChimp via their API. That part of the code is the same as it was when it was working on the AMP site. And AMP had nothing to do with sending that data. So, that really shouldn't be an issue.

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
use \DrewM\MailChimp\Batch;

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $MailChimp = new MailChimp('XXX');

  $list_id = 'XXX';
  $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
  $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
  $interestID = isset($_POST['interestID']) ? $_POST['interestID'] : '';
  $interestLabel = isset($_POST['interestLabel']) ? $_POST['interestLabel'] : '';
  $source = isset($_POST['source']) ? $_POST['source'] : '';
  $subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($email);

  $subscribe = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
    'merge_fields'  => ['FNAME'=>$name, 'MMERGE22'   => $source],
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed'
  ]);

  if ( isset($_POST['interestID']) ) {
    $update= $MailChimp->patch("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash", [
      'email_address' => $email,
      'status'        => 'subscribed',
      'interests'    => [$interestID => true],
    ]);
  }

  if ($MailChimp->success()) {

    $success = array(
      "status" => "success",
      "message" => "Yay! You're subscribed!"
    );

    echo json_encode($success);


  } else {

    $error = array(
      "status" => "error",
      "message" => "Oh no! Something went wrong"
    );

    echo json_encode($error);
  }
}
```

If I comment out the `event.preventDefault()` line to ensure that the browser follows the form action to the PHP form handler, I can see a response of:

```
{"status":"success","message":"Yay! You're subscribed!"}
```

What I get when I submit the form is an error about data.status being null.

data itself is null as well.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: Get rid of `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`. `serialize()` sends the data in URL-encoded format, not JSON.

Comment: In the browser's network tab I can confirm the PHP form handler is returning a 200 response code.

But it looks like the error function in my JavaScript is being executed and not the success function. I console logged err to see what the response was.

I get the follow in the logged response:

`responseText: "400: email@mywebsite.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members.{"status":"error","message":"Oh no! Something went wrong"}"`

That response is coming from MailChimp. If I pass in a new email I'll get a success message.

Comment: You have `dataType: 'json'`. That means the response has to be JSON, it can't include error messages like that.

Comment: Something in the MailChimp library is printing an error message. You need to figure out how to disable that.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to stop MailChimp from printing an error, you can use the output buffering functions to prevent it from being sent in the response.

Comment: Ah.... I left error logging in the implementation of the PHP wrapper.

After I removed that everything works.

Thanks so much. Really really appreciate it.